# Upvote for effort only?

Tags: discussion, voting

I asked a question that got a response that worked for the answerer who was not using the most recent version of the [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) package. Since bugs were fixed for functionality in the new version, I need to have the newest version installed.

I also noticed that, though I included the full object I was working with, the answer included syntax that was evidence that he did not use the exact object I linked.

Nevertheless, I thought the post showed some effort, so I gave him the courtesy of not downvoting him. I thanked him for his effort in the comments. He responded that comments weren't a place to thank people and that I should give him an upvote if I was so thankful. Then downvoted my question.

My question is this: should I upvote him simply for showing effort, though he made two mistakes that result in his code not even running, and that could not be salvaged (other than to use an outdated version of the package)?

I'm not concerned with his downvote abuse here, just asking about an aspect of upvoting.

[OP is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419750/change-line-thickness-in-plotly)

(He deleted his comment on my question; originally saying that I should explain how to use the package, and what version I was using)

Comment: The tooltip on upvote button says _This answer is useful_. If that answer helps you to solve your problem, upvote it.

Comment: If it doesnt help you and/or is not useful, dont upvote it. Effort =/= good result

Comment: "This isn't some grade-school essay contest where you get points just for completing the assignment..." ([Are the Downvoting police too active?](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2500/168))

Comment: Well, it is an accurate comment.  Showing up 4 days later with a "hey, your answer sucks" comment is never appreciated much by anybody.  It is called "human nature". Keep in mind that you are not talking to a machine and be appreciate of the time that SO users invested in trying to help you and you'll easily avoid collisions like this.

Comment: I asked the question late Friday night and returned to it Monday morning with a question. Never said his answer was bad, nor did I downvote it, I was just asking questions to try to understand it

Comment: Side note: "the newest version" means absolutely nothing on posts that expected to stay for years. I don't see why you so against the idea that adding exact version to the post is useful. Imagine someone year from now coming to your post and saying "what a #####, clearly this is trivial with {new latest feature}". Also you may want to read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guidance on creating minimal examples (if it is applicable to "R") - half page of numbers does not feel "minimal" at all.

Comment: I trimmed my data set from thousands of rows down to less than 100 where it had a few series but still some variation. Admittedly, I should have `round()`ed those numbers, but a half page is reasonable for a data table that must have a few series over a decent chunk of time imo.
And someone coming across my post a year from now that finds a trivial function in the newest version **should** add an answer, citing the new version. *They* would be the ones to explain the version issue. That would help future users better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**In general**, your upvotes are your own. You can use them as you see fit, as long as you avoid the classic abuses like serial voting or sockpuppetry.

**In theory**, you should upvote an answer when it is useful or helps you to solve the problem. If you think that an answer that puts a lot of effort in is useful, then upvote it. My point is that effort is not necessarily linked to utility - an answer that had a lot of effort put into it, but addresses the wrong aspect of the problem is still not very useful and should probably be downvoted.

**A note:** be careful of accusing people of downvoting your posts. You can have your suspicions, but the fact that you *can't* see who voted on your stuff is deliberate - you don't know for certain, so don't go throwing accusations of downvoting around. It tends to get people's hackles up.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought.
He originally **said in his comment that he downvoted me** for not having a MRE and not explaining how to use a (commonly used) package, and for not saying that I had the most recent version of the package installed. I quickly put a MRE in. He removed his comment (the downvote remains...)

Comment: @hedgedandlevered It may be someone else's downvote - it's just not possible to tell. But yeah, you'll come across people who downvote things for the hell of it - that's the result of allowing people to vote as they wish, but there isn't really a better way of doing things.

Comment: @PavneetSingh That's... not what upvotes are intended for. You can vote how you like, but if you're trying to use voting as it was intended, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I doubt anonymous down voting  without reasons is a 'better way' ! Any vote has to be useful. Where it doesn't explain the reason, it is just useless action to satisfy the down voter's perception of right and wrong.  But it effects the reputation of the asker. So the balance is horribly skewed against the purpose of this forum !

Comment: I have seen silliest of questions garnering plenty of up votes and serious questions trashed ! This doesn't in any way give credibility to the voting system here !

Comment: @user3526204 i too feel the same,some question are just for code or lack knowledge but once you get downvote even on good question your are done.very few care to read and upvote then plus if you have low repo forget it.seen some guys downvote my answer just to promote theirs.anyway all you need to do is get knowledge and spread knowledge.we are not here to make friends but be respectful to all

Comment: @ArtOfCode yeah i agree with you. i also consider the quality of research of all answer. like i don't go and upvote the topper. what i meant to say is i also read other answers and respect their quality.BTW nice answer.

Comment: @PavneetSingh answer you've linked does not meet SO quality standard as it is simply wall of code. I'd not recommend linking it from META especially with suggestion that it should be upvoted as very good example of detailed answer with good explanation.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov i agree there no good explanation or any explanation at all because the author put a little puzzle and it got me so i solved it plus author interested in code plus he didn't even asked for the explanation at all and if you see, code is pretty constructed from basics fundamentals.i try to be specific in my many other answers. i wanna emphasis on fact that i didn't suggest anyone to upvote, i put the link cuz i got little emotional anyway i apologize for the inconvenience plus i can't remove the link so i am gonna remove the comment.thanks for taking your time to guide me

Comment: *He removed his comment (the downvote remains...)* - Isn't there a only a certain window of time you can change your vote after it's been edited?

Answer (score 3):

Upvotes tend to be viewed as rewards, while downvotes as punishments. That's not the case at all, and it shows clearly by how Stack Overflow handles posts that have been upvoted/downvoted, respectively. Posts with more upvotes tend to appear higher. Questions with more upvotes show higher in some views and answers with more upvotes appear first before other answers.

Conversely, questions with downvotes get buried and eventually even faded, so they are far less visible. Likewise, with answers, downvotes eventually cause them to be buried at the bottom of the page and faded.

The goal here, of course, is to surface good content and bury bad content. If a user comes to a question looking for an answer to a similar problem they are having, the first thing they see is the highest voted answer.

In general, you should think the same way when dealing out upvotes/downvotes. Is this something that someone with a similar issue should ideally see right away? Upvote it. Is this thing not useful to someone with a similar issue? Downvote it. It's that simple. Where the system breaks down is when people don't vote based on *quality* and instead vote as a carrot/stick.